# Skip completely blank cell rows while using sheet_to_json

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I have the following configuration to parse excel to json,which works fine in general:

```
const reader = require('xlsx');
let Data = [];
   Data.push(reader.utils.sheet_to_json(
            file.Sheets[file.SheetNames[0]]))
```

However, If have an excel with 7000 rows. I deleted the values in all but one row for test (there is styling in empty rows such as borders and colors but no values). When parsing, sheetjs still attempts to parse all of 7000 rows for some reason.

How to avoid this and parse only rows that have values in it or avoid pushing such json to Data array ?

Comment: Sheetjs won't know a if a row is empty before first parsing it

Comment: @Shreshth So is there a way to avoid such json being pushed to Data array

Comment: You can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get rids of the empty rows.

Answer (score 2):

see [`blankrows` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#json)

try:

```
Data.push(reader.utils.sheet_to_json(
    file.Sheets[file.SheetNames[0]]), {
    blankrows: false
})
```

Comment: Tried it. But it will work only on blank cells of non-empty rows. Not on completely blank row

Comment: @Immanuel can't reproduce, empty styled cells are skipped. you might have blank spaces within cells..